# Get NavContronner in inner Class

Tags: java, animation, kotlin

```
inner class ProgressBarAnimation(
private val view:View
private val progressBar: ProgressBar,
private val from: Float,
private val to: Float) : Animation() {

 override fun applyTransformation(interpolatedTime: Float, t: Transformation) {
    super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t)
    val value = from + (to - from) * interpolatedTime
    progressBar.progress = value.toInt()
     if(progressBar.progress>=99)
         {
         view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_rideFragment_to_tripPreview)
     }}}
```

class executed in onViewCreated:

```
val anim = ProgressBarAnimation(view,endProgressBar, endProgressBar.progress.toFloat(), 100f)
anim.duration = 1000
endProgressBar.startAnimation(anim)
```

Hello i have a progress bar and if it will be fill, app go to next destination, (progressBar is fill when button is touched) but if it executed i have a error:" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination action_name is unknown to this NavController"

navContronner:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/rideFragment"
        android:label="RideFragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_rideFragment_to_tripPreview"
            app:destination="@id/tripPreview"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
    </fragment>
```

Can u help me with this problem?

Comment: could you show us your `navigation.xml` ?

Comment: Can you edit your post insead, and put it in

Comment: I've done it :D

Comment: I don't see the problems, the error you're getting is from another piece of code. the error you gave us specify `action_name` is unknown. You should do a quick search on that `action_name`

Comment: so it's problem in this inner class because if i write the same code in onCreateView in fragment everything works

Comment: In that case yeah probably

Comment: I solve this problem with another way. I have 1000 milisec animation duration so i if action touch is down i start this handler(1000 milisec) but if the action is up i discard the handler. I am not sure if this is a perfect solution but it works perfectly